# Oracle INSERTING into RAW with UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw

Tags: oracle, raw

I ran into some code that was never implemented (see below).

```
CREATE TABLE encryption_values
(
  NAME   VARCHAR2(6),
  VALUE  NVARCHAR2(100)
);
/

insert into encryption_values
select 'key' name,
rawtohex (
rpad ('52AB32;^$!ER94988OPS3W21@@=WTQ32',32,'X')
) value
from dual
union
select 'iv' name,
rawtohex (
rpad ('TY54ABCX12@÷×+==643QREVDG43AAYMN',32,'X')
) value
from dual;
```

I want to change the table definition from NVARCHAR2(100) to RAW(256). I tried using
UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw()
but I'm running into some syntax errors. Can someone please provide me with the correct syntax. Note I want to keep the RPAD to ensure I'm converting 32 character bytes.

I'm looking to INSERT the data into this table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE encryption_values
(
  NAME   VARCHAR2(6),
  VALUE  RAW(256)
);
/
```

Comment: Did you try just replacing both `rawtohex` calls with `UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw`? What does your current code look like, and what syntax errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong function, `rawtohex`. You must use in your case `cast_to_raw` from the package `utl_raw`

> This function converts a VARCHAR2 value represented using some number
> of data bytes into a RAW value with that number of data bytes. The
> data itself is not modified in any way, but its datatype is recast to
> a RAW datatype.

**Demo**

```
SQL> desc encryption_values
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(6)
 VALUE                                              RAW(256)

SQL> insert into encryption_values
  2  select 'key' name,
  3  utl_raw.cast_to_raw (rpad('52AB32;^$!ER94988OPS3W21@@=WTQ32',32,'X')) value
  4  from dual
  5  union
  6  select 'iv' name,
  7  utl_raw.cast_to_raw (rpad('TY54ABCX12@÷×+==643QREVDG43AAYMN',32,'X')) value
  8* from dual
SQL> /

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from encryption_values ;

NAME
------
VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
iv
5459353441424358313240EFBFBDEFBFBDEFBFBDEFBFBD2B3D3D3634335152455644473433414159

key
3532414233323B5E2421455239343938384F50533357323140403D5754513332
```